# Is possible to convert argument from 'const char []' to 'char *' in C++?

Tags: c++, char

Definition of method is:

```
void setArgument(char *);
```

And i call that method with this code:

```
setArgument("argument");
```

But my VisualStudio compiler gets me the next error:

cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [10]' to 'char *'

Is it possible to send arguments like this or I must change arguments type in the method?
 Also, VS show me next note in output: note: Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that string literals are arrays of ***constant*** characters.

While the array could easily decay to a pointer to its first element, the type of that pointer is `const char *`. Which needs to be the type of the argument for your functions.

And if you need to modify the string you pass, then you should create your own non-constant array:

```
char argument[] = "argument";
setArgument(argument);
```

---

Of course, since you're programming in C++ you should stop using `char` pointers and arrays and instead use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, just if you really need the argument to be mutable (`char*` and not `char const*`), you need to allocate a new storage in the mutable memory and clone the contents of the constant memory to there, if that fits into your definition of "convert".

```
auto const len = strlen(input);
auto const buf = std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[len + 1]);
memcpy(buf, input, len + 1);
```

If you actually need `char const*` and if you are `C++17` or later, you can possibly change the signature to `setArgument(std::string_view arg)`, making it misuse-proof.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen oops... too much java recently, fixed